# RewriteRule, url wrongly displayed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to mod_rewrite and I have this problem:

I have a working redirect with mod_rewrite, my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^microsite/([^/\.]+)/$ micrositecontroller.php?name=$1 [L]
```

micrositecontroller.php only echoes a text

On the browser when I enter my URL:

> localhost/project/microsite/test/

I am redirected to where wanted but when I enter:

> localhost/project/microsite/test

It still redirects to where wanted but the URL becomes like this:

> localhost/project/microsite/test/?name=test

Now what I want is that trailing "/?name=test" not to show up.

I tried different combinations of the regex but to no avail and I have no idea if it is normal of not. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have a slash in your regex, so your regex handles slash... just remove it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^microsite/([^/\.]+)$ micrositecontroller.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I did try that, doing it doesn't redirect where I wanted and the trailing "/?name=test" still appears when I use: localhost/project/microsite/test

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^microsite/([^/\.]+)/?$ micrositecontroller.php?name=$1 [L]
# Note the "?"-------------------^
```

To accommodate both ending with a slash and no slash. The problem with leaving the slash on (or off) is apache forces a browser redirect, thus making the `?name=test` show up in the browser's location bar.

This is because mod_dir and the `DirectorySlash on` directive is interferring. The DirectorySlash directive tells apache to redirect the browser when it accesses what looks to be a directory (in your case `localhost/project/microsite/test` to the smae URI except with a trailing slash.

Comment: Tried but still didn't work: (copy paste)
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^microsite/([^/\.]+)/?$ micrositecontroller.php?name=$1 [L]

It goes where it should but the "?name=test" still shows up

Comment: Is there a `/microsite/test` directory in your document root?

Comment: File structure in www doc root: 
project > microsite > test > index.php,
project > .htaccess , 
project > micrositecontroller.php
These are the main ones that are present and being used.

Comment: Ahh I see, try adding this to the top of your .htaccess file:`DirectorySlash Off`.

Comment: DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^microsite/([^/\.]+)/?$ micrositecontroller.php?name=$1 [L]
 = no change...
Well, I was told that my original code is actually working on the production environment, don't know why on localhost this is happening... Anyways thank you for your contribution.
P.S. Am free to try other proposition, its up to you.